# QGIS crashes when loading a shapefile

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I am using Windows 7, and have installed QGIS 2.2, 2.4, 2.8 and 2.10 to try and resolve this issue, but keep on getting the same response:
Minidump written to.....

This occurs after the programme has loaded, and I want to start adding shapefiles. I have tried shapefiles of varying sizes based on the input found here, but with no luck whatsoever. Whether they are large or small, QGIS will crash.

What could be the problem? I have used QGIS happily on other PCs with Win7.

Comment: Try to think how that certain PC differs from the others. How did you install QGIS? Have you similar user rights on all computers? One possibility is that there are some conflicting libraries on the problematic PC. Removing all QGIS versions and OSGeo4W directory if you have such and re-installing could help.

Comment: Get a similiar report when closing Qgis, saving is not affected: C:/path/qgis-20151115-125013-2984-8572-d20c5b7.dmp. Using Wing7, Qgis 2.10.1

Comment: @user30184 Very little differences in the machines, other than the one is 64bit and the other 32bit. I used the stable installs, and prior to installing the newer versions, or the older as the case may be, I completely cleaned even the registry of any traces of either QGIS or OSGeo4W, but still the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working from, or your shapefiles are on, an external drive, then that makes my QGIS crash sometimes.

Also the bit-version (IE 32- or 64-bit) can make a difference depending on your pc.